# Azure REST API Deleted status

Tags: python, azure

I trying to monitor Azure throught it's REST API from Python using [sdk for python](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-python). Now I am testing it, and for example for [hosted service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460806.aspx), I need to test that I could get `Deleted` status.

But when I delete that hosted sevice from managent console, I just get `WindowsAzureMissingResourceError`.

But then comes the question - **what then does that `status` attribute actually mean, and how to get `Deleted` status**? Because I have to test all cases, or convince my manager that requirements should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you did was deleted a hosted service from the management portal and then queried for the status of that hosted service from your code. Since you deleted the service, you were expecting to receive `Deleted` status however you got `WindowsAzureMissingResourceError`.

This is correct behavior. `WindowsAzureMissingResourceError` is actually `404` error code ([`Resource Not Found`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404)). Since your hosted service is a REST endpoint and it is no longer there (because you deleted it), you should get `404` which the API is returning.

Comment: But how then I could get status `Deleted`?

Comment: You can't because is that resource is not there anymore when you query the resource. What you could do is check the logs and see when a 'Delete' opeartion was performed on that hosted service.